# issue in for loop which is executing once in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, scilab

I have this code which results should be [0,1,2,3,0,3] but I am getting only [0,1,2,3] as output as the loop would be occurring once only.

```
frequ=[[1],[3]]
ppcm=3
den=1
frd1=[[1],[3]]
offset=[ [ 0 ], [ 0 ] ]

for (i = 0; i < frequ.length-1; i++) {

      var matind1 = offset[i] * den;
      var matind2 = frd1[i][0];
      var matind3 = parseFloat(ppcm);
      var mat1 = matindices(offset[i] * den, frd1[i][0], parseFloat(ppcm));
}

    console.log(mat1);

    function matindices(from, diff, to) {
      //fucntion which implements range list of scilab like matindices[1:2:10] gives 1.    3.    5.    7.    9.
      //which was not possible in js so made function
      var arrayind = [];
      for (i = 0; i <= to; i++) {
        arrayind.push(i);
        i = i + diff - 1;
        if (i >= to) {
          return arrayind;
        }
      }


}
```

Comment: I see your expected output, but not quite sure of what your inputs are.

Comment: `offset[i] * den` = `array * number`

Comment: my input are frequ=[[1],[3]]
ppcm=3
den=1
frd1=[[1],[3]]
offset=[ [ 0 ], [ 0 ] ]
which goes into the for loop and inside for loop we call this matindice function

Comment: got the ans missed some iteration in loop and thanks a lott

Answer (score 0):

Your i variable is not defined due to that and other function also using same variable. Try with this,

```
frequ=[[1],[3]]
ppcm=3
den=1
frd1=[[1],[3]]
offset=[ [ 0 ], [ 0 ] ]

for (var j = 0; j < frequ.length; j++) {

      var matind1 = offset[j] * den;
      var matind2 = frd1[j][0];
      var matind3 = parseFloat(ppcm);
      var mat1 = matindices(offset[j] * den, frd1[j][0], parseFloat(ppcm));
  console.log(mat1);
}

    console.log(mat1);

    function matindices(from, diff, to) {
      //fucntion which implements range list of scilab like matindices[1:2:10] gives 1.    3.    5.    7.    9.
      //which was not possible in js so made function
      var arrayind = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= to; i++) {
        arrayind.push(i);
        i = i + diff - 1;
        if (i >= to) {
          return arrayind;
        }
      }
}
```

This will output,

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 3]
```

This code fulfill your requirement,

```
frequ=[[1],[3]]
ppcm=3
den=1
frd1=[[1],[3]]
offset=[ [ 0 ], [ 0 ] ]

var mat1 = [];
for (var j = 0; j < frequ.length; j++) {

      var matind1 = offset[j] * den;
      var matind2 = frd1[j][0];
      var matind3 = parseFloat(ppcm);
      mat1.push.apply(mat1, matindices(offset[j] * den, frd1[j][0], parseFloat(ppcm)));
  //console.log(mat1);
}

    console.log(mat1);

    function matindices(from, diff, to) {
      //fucntion which implements range list of scilab like matindices[1:2:10] gives 1.    3.    5.    7.    9.
      //which was not possible in js so made function
      var arrayind = [];
      for (i = 0; i <= to; i++) {
        arrayind.push(i);
        i = i + diff - 1;
        if (i >= to) {
          return arrayind;
        }
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a simplified for loop, which starts with `from` and takes `diff` as increment value.

At the end of the function return the array, without checking inside of the for loop.

You need to declare all variables in there used scope, as well as in function where you use same named variable `i`, wich may collide with global variables.

Undeclared variables are in Javascript declared as global variables at the first use.

```js
function matindices(from, diff, to) {
    var arrayind = [], i;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i += diff) {
        arrayind.push(i);
    }
    return arrayind;
}

var frequ = [[1], [3]],
    ppcm = 3,
    den = 1,
    offset = [[0], [0]],
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i < frequ.length; i++) {
    console.log(matindices(offset[i][0] * den, frequ[i][0], ppcm));
}
```